# Use Python software without Python interpreter installed on my system

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to understand the basics things.
Before to install the python interpreter on my computer I downloaded Deluge (A torrent client written in Python) and it works without any issue, then I thought I must had Python running but if I run the command:

```
python --version
```

I get the error saying that python is not installed on my computer. How is it possible ? How is the code from Deluge executed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The software you've downloaded probably has python embedded in its distribution, hence it doesn't require you to install it separately.

Also, running `python --version` just tells you that `python` executable isn't in any directories on your `PATH` variable. It doesn't say it's not installed.

If I look at MacOS Deluge distribution, it has `python` bundled with it.

Generally, you need python interpreter to run any python programs.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because what you've download is an executable and does not require Python to be executed.

Comment: There are no real conventional ways to compile python programs into executables. There are tools available, but none of those is a mainstream from what I know. Most people just bundle python with their software and distribute it together.